# Bootstrap Carousel dispose Pictures if small screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello im trying to make the Bootstrap Carousel responsive.

Currently everything works fine, but i want to remove the Images if screen-width is smaller than x px;

```css
.thumbnail>img, .thumbnail a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
    display: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
   
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="/media/1003/banner.png" alt="First slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Title 1</h1>
                    <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/media/1005/banner2.png" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Title 2</h1>
                    <p>Subtitle 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Just make Carousel image 1+2 disapear if screen-width is example: under 400px wide.

Comment: You may add hidden-xs OR hidden-sm classes for small or extra small devicesin the div or a whatever you want to hide.

Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there For make responsive bootstrap carousel you can add some media css according to your html script you can add:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #myCarousel {
     display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how do i get only the "images" of "myCarousel" to disappear?

Comment: It depends on you how you want to show those images on small screen you can use simple HTML img tag.

Comment: Yes works fine but the Carousel has fixed width on all devices, just want to "hide" 
<img src="/media/1003/banner.png" alt="First slide"> and 
<img src="/media/1005/banner2.png" alt="Second slide">

if under 400px, i want to keep the Text and Buttons and stuff

Comment: Okay then as @fruitjs said just add hidden-sm and hidden-xs class into the image tag(if you want to show carousel but not image on small devises) and remove the css  `@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #myCarousel {
     display: none;
   }
}`